# Travis CI can't find Ivy jarfile

Tags: java, ant, ivy, travis-ci

I'm new to Java and Travis CI, and running into an error configuring my project. I'm using ant to build, and ivy to manage dependencies. My ant build downloads an ivy jarfile directly if it's not found locally. This works fine on my machine, but fails when I push to Travis.

The puzzling thing: it looks like it downloads the jar and puts it in `/home/travis/.ant/lib/` during the `bootstrap-ivy` task, but then fails to find it in the `resolve` task that follows. Any idea what's going on? The full error, my ant buildfile, and my `.travis.yml` are all included below.

Here's the full Travis error:

```
Using worker: worker-linux-3-1.bb.travis-ci.org:travis-linux-13
git.1
$ git clone --depth=50 --branch=master git://github.com/ecmendenhall/Java-TTT.git ecmendenhall/Java-TTT
Cloning into 'ecmendenhall/Java-TTT'...
remote: Counting objects: 613, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (345/345), done.
remote: Total 613 (delta 325), reused 421 (delta 133)
Receiving objects: 100% (613/613), 102.29 KiB, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (325/325), done.
$ cd ecmendenhall/Java-TTT
git.2
$ git checkout -qf 3a5201cc7e850d7cbad69712fce28a36c86ea6d1
$ jdk_switcher use oraclejdk7
Switching to Oracle JDK7 (java-7-oracle), JAVA_HOME will be set to /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for apt.
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for mozilla-javaplugin.so.
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for apt.
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_17"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_17-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)
$ javac -version
javac 1.7.0_17
$ ant resolve
Buildfile: /home/travis/build/ecmendenhall/Java-TTT/build.xml
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/travis/build/ecmendenhall/Java-TTT/lib
check-ivy:
     [echo] Checking for Ivy .jar in local directories.
bootstrap-ivy:
     [echo] Bootstrapping Ivy installation.
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/travis/.ant/lib
      [get] Getting: http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/ivy/ivy/2.3.0/ivy-2.3.0.jar
      [get] To: /home/travis/.ant/lib/ivy.jar
resolve:
     [echo] Resolving project dependencies.
BUILD FAILED
/home/travis/build/ecmendenhall/Java-TTT/build.xml:52: Problem: failed to create task or type antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant:retrieve
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
No types or tasks have been defined in this namespace yet
This appears to be an antlib declaration. 
Action: Check that the implementing library exists in one of:
        -/usr/share/ant/lib
        -/home/travis/.ant/lib
        -a directory added on the command line with the -lib argument
Total time: 3 seconds
The command "ant resolve" failed and exited with 1 during install.
Your build has been stopped.
```

Here's my ant buildfile:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="TicTacToe" basedir="." default="jar" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">
    <description>Builds the TicTacToe command line application and its associated tests.</description>

    <!-- Source and build directory defaults -->
    <property name="src.dir" value="src"/>
    <property name="resources.dir" value="resources"/>

    <property name="build.dir" value="build"/>
    <property name="classes.dir" value="${build.dir}/classes"/>
    <property name="jar.dir" value="${build.dir}/jar"/>

    <property name="main-class" value="com.cmendenhall.Main"/>

    <mkdir dir="lib" />
    <property name="lib.dir" value="lib"/>
    <property name="test.dir" value="test" />

    <path id="classpath">
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
    </path>

    <path id="classpath.test">
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="${classes.dir}" />
        <pathelement location="${resources.dir}" />
    </path>

    <path id="application" location="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar"/>

    <!-- Automatically download Ivy -->
    <property name="ivy.jar.dir" value="${user.home}/.ant/lib" />
    <property name="ivy.jar.file" value="${ivy.jar.dir}/ivy.jar" />

    <target name="check-ivy" unless="INTERN-ivy.jar.exists" description="Check if the Ivy .jar is already installed.">
        <echo message="Checking for Ivy .jar in local directories." />
        <available property="INTERN-ivy.jar.exists" file="${ivy.jar.file}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="bootstrap-ivy"
            description="Installs the Ivy jar before downloading dependencies."
            unless="INTERN-ivy.jar.exists"
            depends="check-ivy">
        <echo message="Bootstrapping Ivy installation." />
        <mkdir dir="${user.home}/.ant/lib"/>
        <get dest="${user.home}/.ant/lib/ivy.jar"
             src="http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/ivy/ivy/2.3.0/ivy-2.3.0.jar"/>
        <mkdir dir="/usr/share/ant/lib" />
        <get dest="/usr/share/ant/lib/ivy.jar"
             src="http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/ivy/ivy/2.3.0/ivy-2.3.0.jar" />
    </target>

    <target name="resolve" description="Retrieve dependencies with Ivy." depends="check-ivy, bootstrap-ivy">
        <echo message="Resolving project dependencies." />
        <ivy:retrieve />
    </target>

    <target name="clean" description="Cleans up automatically generated files and directories.">
        <echo message="Cleaning up build directory." />
        <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile" depends="resolve" description="Compiles project.">
        <echo message="Compiling project." />
        <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
        <javac includeantruntime="false" debug="true" srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" >
            <classpath refid="classpath" />
        </javac>
    </target>

    <target name="compile-tests" depends="resolve" description="Compiles JUnit tests." >
        <echo message="Compiling JUnit tests." />
        <javac includeantruntime="false" debug="true" srcdir="${test.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" >
            <classpath refid="classpath" />
        </javac>
    </target>

    <target name="jar" depends="compile" description="Packages project as .jar file.">
        <echo message="Packaging project as .jar file." />
        <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
        <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-class" value="${main-class}"/>
            </manifest>
            <fileset dir="${classes.dir}">
                <include name="**/*.class" />
            </fileset>
            <fileset dir="${resources.dir}">
                <include name="**/*.properties" />
            </fileset>
        </jar>
    </target>

    <property name="junitpath" refid="classpath.test" />


    <target name="test" depends="compile, compile-tests" description="Runs JUnit tests.">
        <echo message="Running JUnit tests." />
        <junit printsummary="on" haltonfailure="yes" failureproperty="test.failure">
            <jvmarg value="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8:-XX:-UseSplitVerifier" />
            <formatter type="brief" usefile="false" />
            <classpath>
                <path refid="classpath.test"/>
            </classpath>

            <batchtest fork="on">
                <fileset id="matchedtests" dir="${classes.dir}">
                    <include name="**/*Test.class"/>
                    <exclude name="**/TicTacToeTest.class" />
                </fileset>
            </batchtest>
        </junit>
    </target>

    <target name="clean-build" depends="clean, jar" description="Cleans output directory and builds .jar.">
        <echo message="Cleaning build directory and rebuilding .jar." />
    </target>

    <target name="build-all" depends="clean, jar, test" description="Cleans output directory, retrieves dependencies, builds and packages project and tests.">
        <echo message="Finishing build." />
    </target>

</project>
```

And here's my `.travis.yml`:

```
language: java
install: ant resolve
jdk:
  - oraclejdk7
  - openjdk7
  - openjdk6
```

**UPDATE**:
Here's the solution that worked for me, thanks to the advice below.

I replaced my custom `bootstrap-ivy` task with the `download-ivy` and `init-ivy` tasks recommended in the [official docs](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/install.html):

```
    <property name="ivy.install.version" value="2.1.0-rc2" />
    <condition property="ivy.home" value="${env.IVY_HOME}">
      <isset property="env.IVY_HOME" />
    </condition>
    <property name="ivy.home" value="${user.home}/.ant" />
    <property name="ivy.jar.dir" value="${ivy.home}/lib" />
    <property name="ivy.jar.file" value="${ivy.jar.dir}/ivy.jar" />

    <target name="download-ivy" unless="offline">

        <mkdir dir="${ivy.jar.dir}"/>
        <!-- download Ivy from web site so that it can be used even without any special installation -->
        <get src="http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ivy/ivy/${ivy.install.version}/ivy-${ivy.install.version}.jar" 
             dest="${ivy.jar.file}" usetimestamp="true"/>
    </target>

    <target name="init-ivy" depends="download-ivy">
      <!-- try to load ivy here from ivy home, in case the user has not already dropped
              it into ant's lib dir (note that the latter copy will always take precedence).
              We will not fail as long as local lib dir exists (it may be empty) and
              ivy is in at least one of ant's lib dir or the local lib dir. -->
        <path id="ivy.lib.path">
            <fileset dir="${ivy.jar.dir}" includes="*.jar"/>

        </path>
        <taskdef resource="org/apache/ivy/ant/antlib.xml"
                 uri="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant" classpathref="ivy.lib.path"/>
    </target>
```

I added a `before_install` step to `.travis.yml`, which runs `ant init-ivy` before trying to resolve dependencies ([Here are the docs](http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/build-configuration/#Build-Lifecycle) on the Travis build cycle):

```
language: java
before_install: ant init-ivy
install: ant resolve
jdk:
  - oraclejdk7
  - openjdk7
  - openjdk6
```

Now everything's working!

Comment: One extra thing. Installing ivy into ${user.home}/.ant/lib should be enough. You don't need to install two jars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is related to the way Ant is loading the jars from `.ant/lib`. This folder is being looked up at the very boot of Ant, and if any jar is found there is it then added to its core classloader. Here the `.ant/lib` is being populated while executing the build, so it is way too late.

Two choices to resolve this:

- launch ant twice; one to populate `.ant/lib`, another to do the actual build
- instead of putting the jar of Ivy in `.ant/lib`, just put it in an arbitrary place and load it via the `taskdef` Ant task. See the 'Automatically' section of http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/install.html

Comment: +1 The simplest way to run ANT twice is to create two build steps within the Travis job (I'm more familiar with Jenkins, but principles are the same).